# joomla newsflash module -two identical modules-different behavior

Tags: joomla

I have created two newsflash modules placed side by side in the home page,each module displays the intro of an article(from a different category).

but although the 2 modules are almost identical ,in the first module the link 'read more' works ok ,and redirect to a separate page with the full article text (url---> myweb/category/the article),but strangely the second module when clicking on the 'read more' button the article open the full text article in the home page and doesnt redirect to separate page ?
why is that?
(latest joomla version)

solved thank you Elin

Comment: I'm trying to think about what you might mean by "just open the full text article i the home page."  I think what you may mean there is that the article opens and the layout in terms of modules and templates is the same as that for the home page. Is that right? And the other one has different modules?

Comment: hi thank you and sorry ,my english is not that good:(  I will try to explain again: I have placed in my home page 2 identical modules(newsflash) .but for some reason they behave differently when pressing the 'read more' button. In one of them,the  'read more' link leads to a separate page with the full article, but in the second module  the 'read more' link doesn't lead to a separate page.I dont know why:(

Comment: Explain what you mean by "separate page" ... most likely the settings for the display of the two articles are different. One may have a menu link somewhere and one may not, for example.

Comment: separate page -myweb.com --> click on the read more link ----->goes to myweb.com/category/article

Comment: and the other one?  Though what's happing is probably that the second one has a menu link so that the modules etc are set by that, and the first one has no menu link so it is getting the defaults.

Comment: yes I think you are right the second link is actually not the home page as I thought (though visually it looks alike) the link is -->myweb/randomletters/category/article

Comment: thank you Elin you were correct only one of the module was properly linked to menu item,thank you very much!